# Find the latest SVN tag

Tags: svn, version-control, continuous-integration

I am setting up a Continuous Integration job that patches an external library and releases the patched version locally.

However, the external library uses TRUNK for development, and I would like my CI job to automatically select the latest release tag for checkout.

Does SVN have that functionality?

(bash Shell Scripts are ok)

Comment: Just found this similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/68139/get-latest-tag-from-subversion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hm...What about the following:

```
svn log URL/tags --limit 1
```

will print out the last tag.

Answer (score 10):

This will work if nothing better can be found:

```
svn log -v <tagsurl> | awk '/^   A/ { print $2 }' | grep -v RC |  head -1
```

(the grep -v RC part strips release candidates)

**Source:** [this answer to a previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/68139/get-latest-tag-from-subversion/68156#68156)

Comment: This worked better for me since I needed the tag URL, not info.

Comment: use --limit 1 along with log -v to save on time to get latest tag. `svn log -v <tagsurl> --limit 1 | awk '/^   A/ { print $2 }'`

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a more generic solution. Sometimes we don't only need the latest tag, but the latest tag which respect a pattern :

```
last_tag=$(svn ls http://svn_rep/XXX/tags/ | egrep '^MySpecialProject_V([0-9].)+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z_0-9]*' | sort --reverse | head -1 2>&1)
```

Here we will have the latest tag of the project whose name starts by **MySpecialProject_V**.
And if we had these tags :

```
Koko_V3.1.0.0
MySpecialProject_V1.1.0.0
MySpecialProject_V1.2.0.0
MySpecialProject_V2.1.0.0
MySpecialProject_V2.2.0.0
```

The result of :

```
echo $last_tag
```

...would be :

```
MySpecialProject_V2.2.0.0
```

I hope this would help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, you could use powershell:

```
$path = (([Xml] (svn log --xml $Url --verbose --username $Username --password $Password)).Log.LogEntry.Paths.Path |
? { $_.action -eq 'A' -and $_.kind -eq 'dir' -and $_.InnerText -like '*tags*'} |
Select -Property @(
    @{N='date'; E={$_.ParentNode.ParentNode.Date}},
    @{N='path'; E={$_.InnerText}} )|
Sort Date -Descending |
Select -First 1).path
```

Where $Url is the url of you tags

Answer (score -2):

Svn has no definition of *tag*. I assume you mean *revision*. The symbolic revision *HEAD* points to the latest revision of a tree.

e.g.
`svn export -rHEAD ...`

Comment: I know there is no real definition of a tag, but I mean the pseudo-tag thingies in `tags` next to `trunk`

Comment: It's a very common usage. So we assume his repo is structured in `trunk branches tags` like most of us.